# Editing docker volume data on host not changing inside container?

Tags: javascript, docker, vim, docker-volume

I am making application in docker environment. (toolbox)
I work on the local PC by sharing the volumn.
When editing a js file, it can not be modified on the website.
However, I can change the js file to vi in the docker container.

Cache does not seem to be the cause. What is the cause ???

Answer (score 1):

**Don't edit from outside the container. It is the limitation of mount.**

> If you are using some editor like vim, when you save the file it does
>   not save the file directly, rather it creates a new file and copies it
>   into place. This breaks the bind-mount, which is based on inode. Since
>   saving the file effectively changes the inode, changes will not
>   propagate into the container. When the container is restarted the new
>   inode. If you edit the file in place you should see changes propagate.
>
> This is a known limitation of file-mounts and is not fixable.

taken from [github comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15793#issuecomment-135411504)

[Known Issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15793) on github